# Google Apps is routing mail unexpectedly

Tags: domain-name-system, email, g-suite, cname-record

This has been going on for two days now and it's really bugging me.

I've owned a domain name for a few years now. Let's call it `example.com`. I've had Google Apps free edition set up there for a few years and all is good. `example.com` has an A record pointing at a VPS that I own and MX records pointing at Google. I also have all email from `example.com` forwarded to my personal gmail account.

Just recently I registered a domain name for my friend's business that he is starting and set him up with Google Apps free edition. Let's called it `example.net`. This domain has MX records pointing at Google and a CNAME pointing at `example.com` -- I am using virtual hosts on my VPS to determine which page to serve -- basic stuff.

Here's the problem. All email sent to `example.net` ends up at `example.com`. Would the CNAME cause this? And why would it? I didn't think that CNAME records affect email. There are *no* filters set up for any email at `example.net`.

In the email headers I see `To: friend@example.net`. Moving up the header I see this out of nowhere:

```
X-Forwarded-To: personal@gmail.com
X-Forwarded-For: me@example.com personal@gmail.com
```

The only explanation I can think of is the CNAME record pointing from `example.net` to `example.com`. Can anybody verify this for me or possibly name another reason for this to happen?

Comment: If only there were a domain name specifically reserved for examples... [Oh, wait.](http://www.iana.org/go/rfc2606)

Comment: As for X-Forwarded, probably it's normal because it google forwards it from _your_ apps to your private gmail. Guess you see it in all messages to example.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a `CNAME` record on `domain2.com` takes precedence over any other record on `domain2.com`.

According to the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2181.txt), no other type of resource record (be it `A`, `MX`, or otherwise, except for DNSSEC supporting types `SIG`, `NXT`, and `KEY`) can exist on the same name as a `CNAME`; a BIND name server won't even load a zone with that kind of conflict present.

Comment: Well then, I learned something today. I'll just have to update the DNS records (and accept your answer in 9 minutes when ServerFault lets me).

Comment: @KPthunder Can we edit "incorrectly" to "correctly" in your question now? :-)

Comment: @ceejayoz I changed it to "unexpectedly." Is that good enough? :P

Comment: It does not actually explain why emails end-up in example.com mailbox - ok, CNAME causes that MX from example.com used, those MX point to the very same google apps as MX in example.net. now sendmail goes to those servers and sends mail to:example.NET.   How came it end-up in example.com mailbox ?

Comment: @KPThunder change it back to "incorrectly" ? ;)

Comment: @Sandman4 Hah, good point!

Comment: @KPthunder Hehe. Thanks for being a good sport. :-)

Comment: @Sandman4 I removed the CNAME and changed it to an A record of the same IP address of my VPS and now everything works unlike the last two days.

Comment: @ceejayoz No problem, brah.

Comment: I demand someone to explain WHY ! :)

Comment: @sandman4: it happens because when a CNAME is encountered the sending SMTP server is at liberty to rewrite the recipient address to the target of the CNAME (i.e. example.net CNAME example.com; user@example.net is rewriteable to user@example.com.) Then example.com happily accepts the mail.  But you should never use CNAME at the top-level of a zone anyway: It's not valid (as highlighted above). Use the same IP address if you were doing it for a web server, etc., and manage any future changes.